# How to create spring security login page in vaadin with Java only?

Tags: java, spring, security, authentication, vaadin

I'm currently building an web app with spring and vaadin. I searched for days to find a solution to create a custom login page with vaadin for spring security. I've got the layout, but don't know how to send the username and password to spring.... 
Can anybody help me or show me a good example?

By the way I'm using vaadin 10.

Comment: This should be possible using a `AuthenticationProvider#authenticate` call. I am not sure but Spring Boot should already auto-configure one. For normal spring application you need to configure it manually I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed it by created a Route for the login page with Vaadin and created a custom AuthenticationService that puts the Authentication Object into the SecurityContextHolder.

Answer (score 1):

Vaadin 13 introduces dedicated login components you can use. They will send the form data to the configured endpoint Spring Security is listening to:

```java
@Tag("sa-login-view")
@Route(value = LoginView.ROUTE)
@PageTitle("Login")
public class LoginView extends VerticalLayout {
        public static final String ROUTE = "login";

        private LoginOverlay login = new LoginOverlay(); // (1)

        public LoginView(){
            login.setAction("login"); // (2)
            login.setOpened(true); // (3)
            login.setTitle("Spring Secured Vaadin");
            login.setDescription("Login Overlay Example");
            getElement().appendChild(login.getElement()); // (4)
        }
}
```

This code snippet is part of a tutorial about Vaadin and Spring Security in general. Check https://vaadin.com/tutorials/securing-your-app-with-spring-security. Right now a section about a page reload free solution is in progress.

Answer (score 0):

If you've configured Spring to use `formLogin()`, you can just submit the data in a normal form.

```
<form method="POST" action="login">
    <input name="username" />
    <input name="password" />
    <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
</form>
```

If you want to use Vaadin components inside, you need to wrap everything in an `iron-form`

```
<iron-form id="ironForm" allow-redirect="true">
    <form method="POST" action="login">
        <vaadin-text-field name="username"></vaadin-text-field>
        <vaadin-password-field name="password"></vaadin-password-field>

        <vaadin-button theme="primary" on-click="_submit">
            Log in
        </vaadin-button>
    </form>
</iron-form>
```

and manually submit the form when the Vaadin button is clicked

```
_submit() {
    this.$.ironForm.submit();
}
```